# Ubuntu 22.04 reboots randomly due to systemd automatic upgrades?

Tags: snap, reboot

I left my computer running overnight and it looks like it randomly decided to reboot at around 6 in the morning. This is the output of the relevant lines from `sudo journalctl -b -1 -n2000`:

```
Dec 08 06:15:49 danilaberezin-workstation systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Dec 08 06:15:50 danilaberezin-workstation systemd[1]: Stopping Session 92 of User danila...
```

I think the reboot was caused by the daily upgrade service, but not positive.

Here is the output of my `lsb_release -a`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Can the person who downvoted this question at least explain why you downvoted? Thanks.

Comment: Your log fragment begins too late. All you see is processes responding to a shutdown. The actual shutdown happened earlier. Read `man journalctl less`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the `journalctl` logs more thoroughly, looks like the reboot was caused by systemd trying to do upgrades and cleanups. After doing some more digging I found this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1327884/how-to-disable-daily-upgrade-and-clean-on-ubuntu-16-04. Followed the advice in the answer there. Not sure if it will work in preventing future reboots.